# Prove a functions is injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Prove the function
 $f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}$
defined by $f(x)=2^x$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$ is one to one.

Is my proof correct and if not what errors are there.

> For all $x_1,x_2$ $\in$$N$, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1=x_2$
>   $f(x)=2^x$
>   Assume $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and show $x_1=x_2$
>   $2^{x_1}=2^{x_2}$
>   $x_1=x_2$ , which means $f$ is injective.

Comment: You may want to apply induction here (since you're supposed to be writing a proof, not just stating facts).

Comment: Well the question asked for me to prove the statement.Is what i did not a proof? I just used contrapositive. Would this affect how the question will be marked?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you got it down. I don't see any errors in comprehension; just a little redundancy in the layout of the proof. If I were to make changes I would completely do away with the line "For all $x_1,x_2$ $\in$$N$, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $x_1=x_2$
$f(x)=2^x$" then edit the rest of your proof to read

"Assume $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then 
$$2^{x_1}=2^{x_2} \\ \implies \frac{2^{x_1}}{2^{x_1}} = \frac{2^{x_2}}{2^{x_1}} \\ \implies 1 = 2^{x_2-x_1}$$ And we know $a^b = 0$ whenever $a \neq 0$ and $b = 0$. Hence, $x_1-x_2=0$ so $f$ is one-to-one."

Comment: @graydad does this kind of assume that we know inverse, $\log_2$ is injective?

Comment: @Kamster erm... possibly? Depends on what OP is allowed to use to complete this proof. I'll edit my answer to be on the safe side.

Comment: yea it just seemed weird sometimes in injective proofs to use the inverse function. But then again I couldnt think explicitly how to do it other wise